# Swift and UILabel - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

When I try to set the a UILabel in Swift the app crashes and I get an error saying: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Here is my code, it crashes when I set the frame.

```
var newsFeed1: UILabel!
let Description = object!["Description"] as! String
newsFeed1.frame = CGRect(x: 22.5, y: 315, width: 475, height: 50)
newsFeed1.text = Description
storeTab.addSubview(newsFeed1)
```

Comment: where do you assign a value to `newsFeed1`? You are missing the line `newsFeed1 = UILabel()`!

Comment: Also check that whatever `object` is is not `nil`

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks I just noticed I forgot that

Answer (score 0):

Your code crashes because you try to unwrap the optional `newsFeed1` which is nil - by using the `!` you tell the program that there HAS to be something different than nil, which there is not. Since you never assign anything and apprently are not connecting it as an outlet either.

To fix the issue you have to assign something to `newsFeed1` - before accessing any property of it you have to put the following line:

```
newsFeed1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 22.5, y: 315, width: 475, height: 50))
```